# Converted to firewalld and Now "No route to host" Error Between Subnets in a Zone

Tags: networking, linux-networking, firewalld

I have a router running Debian 10 that I have been using for years. Yesterday I decided to convert from `iptables` to `firewalld` because I needed to beef up my security and support some new networks in the future. But for now I'm keeping things simple.

The good news is that I'm able to route traffic from devices on my **home** zone to the internet, which is 90% of the router's job. The bad news is that now I'm getting `no route to host` errors when I try to cross subnets within my **home** zone. This didn't use to be the case so I think it has something to do with `firewalld`.

Here's an example of me trying to ssh into a computer on the 10.0.0.0 network from one on the 10.0.1.0 network:

```
$ ssh foo@libreelec
ssh: connect to host libreelec port 22: No route to host
```

However, I can definitely route to it using ping:

```
$ ping libreelec
PING libreelec (10.0.0.29) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from LibreELEC (10.0.0.29): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=5.05 ms
...
```

Here's how `firewalld` is setup on my router:

```
Zones:
--> home
----> eth1 (10.0.1.0/24)
----> wlan0 (10.0.0.0/24)
--> public
----> eth0 (73.xxx.77.xxx/23) / Interface to my modem
```

Here's what my **home** zone config looks like:

```
home (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlan0 eth1
  sources:
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client dhcp dns
  ports: 9000/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

...and here's my routing table (which *hasn't* changed):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         73.246.76.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
73.xxx.76.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     204    0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     305    0        0 wlan0
```

Is this a common issue when people switch to `firewalld`? Is there anything I can do at a router level that unblocks this route between the two subnets in the **home** zone?

**Update 1**

Michael Hampton asked me to post the output of the `iptables -Lnv` command but I got a `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.` error when I did that. However, here's the output of `iptables -S`:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_home
-N FWDI_home_allow
-N FWDI_home_deny
-N FWDI_home_log
-N FWDI_public
-N FWDI_public_allow
-N FWDI_public_deny
-N FWDI_public_log
-N FWDO_home
-N FWDO_home_allow
-N FWDO_home_deny
-N FWDO_home_log
-N FWDO_public
-N FWDO_public_allow
-N FWDO_public_deny
-N FWDO_public_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_home
-N IN_home_allow
-N IN_home_deny
-N IN_home_log
-N IN_public
-N IN_public_allow
-N IN_public_deny
-N IN_public_log
-N OUTPUT_direct
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i eth1 -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i wlan0 -g FWDI_home
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i eth0 -g FWDI_home
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o eth1 -g FWDO_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o wlan0 -g FWDO_home
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o eth0 -g FWDO_home
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_home -j FWDI_home_log
-A FWDI_home -j FWDI_home_deny
-A FWDI_home -j FWDI_home_allow
-A FWDI_home -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_home -j FWDO_home_log
-A FWDO_home -j FWDO_home_deny
-A FWDO_home -j FWDO_home_allow
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A FWDO_public_allow -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_ZONES -i eth1 -g IN_public
-A INPUT_ZONES -i wlan0 -g IN_home
-A INPUT_ZONES -i eth0 -g IN_home
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A IN_home -j IN_home_log
-A IN_home -j IN_home_deny
-A IN_home -j IN_home_allow
-A IN_home -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_home_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_home_allow -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_home_allow -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_home_allow -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_home_allow -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_home_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_home_allow -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_home_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Michael, does this iptables output provide the information for which you were looking?

Answer (score 1):

I think this ended up being a duplicate of this question:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347773/forward-traffic-between-two-firewalld-interfaces-in-the-same-zone#422124

I ended up running commands that are similar to this and I was able to make the hosts in the two subnets within the HOME zone communicate on every port:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -o enxd8eb97b84051 -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i enxd8eb97b84051 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --reload
```